# Mobilenet for keras

Tags: python, keras

Following is the architecture for my model.

```
# %%
# Defining the model
input_shape = img_data[0].shape

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.75))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
# model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.75))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.75))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
# model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd,metrics=["accuracy"])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The accuracy is bit low. so I want to transorm the architecture to mobilenet. Is there any keras based implementation to classify images using mobilenet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras has a set of pretrained model for image classification purposes.
You can check the list and the usage [here](https://keras.io/applications/)

You can also copy the implementation of the architecture on the github repository, [here the link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/mobilenet.py)

Comment: How do I retrain the existing model as in tensorflow image classifier?

Comment: Please check the examples: https://keras.io/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models

The InceptionV3 example is useful for you

Comment: okay.. please quoting any gist or sample project will help a lot since Im new to this...

Comment: I don't know any other reference. If I'll keep you update if I find something.
Is the question closed or you need more information?

Comment: ya please let me know...it will save my life

Answer (score 4):

May be this code snip will help you

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from keras.applications.mobilenetv2 import MobileNetV2
from  keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, SGD
import keras
from tensorflow import confusion_matrix
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import config
import numpy as np

train_path = 'data/train'
val_batch = 'data/val'
test_batch = 'data/test'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(config.IMAGE_SIZE, config.IMAGE_SIZE),
                                                         class_mode='categorical', batch_size=20)
val_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(val_batch, target_size=(config.IMAGE_SIZE, config.IMAGE_SIZE),
                                                         class_mode='categorical', batch_size=20)

def prepare_image(file):
    img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(config.IMAGE_SIZE, config.IMAGE_SIZE))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_expanded_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    return keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(img_expanded_dims)

mobilenet = MobileNetV2()

# x =  mobilenet.layers[-6].output
x =  mobilenet.layers[-2].output
predictions =  Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)
from keras import Model
model = Model(inputs= mobilenet.input, outputs=predictions)

print(model.summary())



# for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
#     layer.trainable = False


# for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
#     layer.trainable = False

print(model.summary())

# exit(0)


model.compile(SGD(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_batches, steps_per_epoch=10,
                    validation_data=val_batches, validation_steps=10, epochs=300, verbose=2)

acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()

plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

# Get the ground truth from generator
ground_truth = train_batches.classes

# Get the label to class mapping from the generator
label2index = train_batches.class_indices

# Getting the mapping from class index to class label
idx2label = dict((v, k) for k, v in label2index.items())

print(idx2label)


# _, val_labels =  next(val_batches)
#
# predictions = model.predict_generator(val_batches, steps=1, verbose=0)
#
# cm = confusion_matrix(val_batches, np.round(predictions[:,0]))
# cm_plot_labels = []
#
# for k, v in label2index.items():
#     cm_plot_labels.append(v)
#
# print(cm)



# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("mobilenet.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

from keras.models import save_model
save_model(model, 'mobilenet.h5')


import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow.contrib import lite
# tf.lite.TocoConverter

converter = tf.lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file("mobilenet.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("model/mobilenet.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: I think the question is how to add the transfer learning model to the existing architecture he showed. You have completely rewritten the syntax to no longer follow the model.add() way of building a model.